# Editing strings with exponents, potential bug

Tags: bugs, front-end, editing

**Bug introduced in 8.0. or earlier, persisting through 11.0.1.**

I know this site is not fond of screenshots, but this is the only way I could think of to communicate this behavior. When editing expressions that contain strings with exponents, such as `Quantity` expressions, the exponents can disappear.

[image: screenshot illustrating exponent removal]

This has been sent to Wolfram as a bug report but not yet confirmed. As mentioned in the screenshot, the workaround is to not attempt typeset exponents, just use the carat `^`

Comment: You can consider [making a .gif](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1059/1871) :) . Also, this issue isn't related to unit, it can be reproduced without `Quantity`.

Comment: maybe related: [Issue with undo after copying a string inside a string](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116521/5478)

Answer (score 3):

This question earned me a "tumbleweed" badge, so I am answering it just to close it out.  The behavior was reproduced by Wolfram tech support, but I did not get a follow-up from a developer. My workaround is to avoid typeset exponents in `Quantity` unit expressions.

Comment: I wouldn't hold your breath on the follow-up. I reported this bug to Wolfram in Aug. 2009 for Mathematica version 7.